# We make an appointment TO / FOR a dentist or physician?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I choose? (When I want to say that we need to have an appointment for treatment)

> We make an appointment **to** a dentist.

Or

> We make an appointment **for** a dentist.

Or maybe other preposition?

N.b. I can guess that the preposition "for" denotes that the dentist by himself is sick and the appointment is for him. But I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FumbleFingers said in comments, the most likely use the preposition **with**:

> We need to make an appointment **with** a dentist.

Also, we often use the direct article to mean either "my regular dentist" or even "any dentist in general":

> We need to make an appointment with **the** dentist.

We'd most likely use the indefinite article **a** in a case where the person making the appointment does not regularly go to the dentist.

But really, the most natural usage is not to use a preposition at all.  We'd use either a possessive or a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct):

> We need to make a **dentist's** appointment.
>
> We need to make a **dentist** appointment.

Either form is correct - I would personally use the possessive, but the non-possessive looks natural to me as well (and in rapidly-spoken English, you can barely detect the difference between the two).

Interestingly enough, the popularity of the possessive is different for different medical professionals.  For **dentist**, using [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams), it looks like the non-possessive has been the most common usage since about 1965:

[image: dentist appointment]

But for **doctor**, the possessive is by far the most common (in fact, "doctor appointment" sounds unnatural to me):

[image]

I am guessing that this is purely a matter of pronunciation: it's difficult to pronounce the [sts] cluster at the end of **dentist's** distinctly, so people just leave off the final [s] and that has migrated to written English as well.  The [rs] at the end of **doctor's** is easy to pronounce, so it has remained the preferred usage.

Comment: Your "Google NGram" link just has the default (*Albert Einstein*, etc.) search terms. [This is the one you want.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+dentist+appointment%2Ca+dentist%27s+appointment%2Can+appointment+with+the+dentist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20dentist%20appointment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20dentist%20%27s%20appointment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20appointment%20with%20the%20dentist%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Note your link is broken because of the way apostrophes are handled in URLs.  I can't link directly to a search with apostrophes, so I linked to the default Ngram page instead.

Comment: Note that if you switch to the BrE corpus, it's noticeable that Brits remain more firmly wedded to the ***appointment with the...*** version for ***...dentist.*** But with ***doctor***, everyone is much happier with the apostrophized form (and almost ***no-one*** likes the bare ***I have a doctor appointment tomorrow*** version).

Comment: My first link isn't ***completely*** broken. If you just click on the ***search lots of books*** button, you'll get the chart. With the "default" link, you'd have a lot more work to do entering the search terms by hand.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I see that you're using the article **the**, which is an interesting distinction from the OP's use of **a** - I'll edit my answer to discuss this usage.

Comment: Haha - to make it a truly level playing field, perhaps we should go for [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+dentist+appointment%2Ca+dentist%27s+appointment%2C%28an+appointment+with+the+dentist%2Ban+appointment+with+a+dentist%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20dentist%20appointment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20dentist%20%27s%20appointment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28an%20appointment%20with%20the%20dentist%20%2B%20an%20appointment%20with%20a%20dentist%29%3B%2Cc0) (summing all hits for *...with **the / a** dentist*).

Answer (score 2):

In AmE you can say:

> I have to make a dentist appointment.
>
> I have to make a dentist's appointment.
>
> I have to make an appointment with the dentist.
>
> I have to make an appointment to see the dentist.
>
> I have to make an appointment for the dentist.

Even that last one, which seems as though you're saying that you're making an appointment *on behalf of* the dentist, can mean that you need to see the dentist. There, "the dentist" is a kind of metonymy for "dental work" or "a dental checkup".

It's like saying

> I have to make an appointment for my annual state automobile inspection.

There, the object of **for** is the service that will be performed, and that is the meaning above, with **for the dentist** as well, although in a roundabout way where "the dentist" stands for the services performed at a dental office.

We can even ask

> How did the dentist go?

and we mean "How did your dental appointment turn out?"

It's like asking

> How was church?